# selection cursor is in editText, but the soft keyboard is not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, keyboard, android-edittext

I'm writing an android application.

In my view, there is a editText.

When the activity starts the selection cursor is in the editText

but the soft keyboard comes out only after double tapping the editText.

I want the cursor to appear only when the keyboard is out.

How can I hide the selection cursor till the user tap the editText and the keyboard is out?

Comment: As far as I know there are no method that can fulfil your demand.

Comment: is linearlayout focusable? or is clear focus method to editText?

Comment: There is an attribute named *cursorFocusable*, I have only tried it in     layout xml file, if it is set false, it will never show the cursor even you touch the EditText.

Comment: @twlkyao this is not what i'm looking for